# How do I find the largest value of a cell in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My issue is that I have a Fuel Transaction list of vehicles and their registration numbers and I need to find out the latest odometer readings that have been recorded for each vehicle which are in a different column. How do I use the registration number and compare that to the odometer reading column and return the latest odometer reading?

'latest' is in descending order, each row going down is a new transaction for the vehicle.

Also note, the latest odometer reading might be lower than a previous transaction because some of the people enter random odometer values when purchasing fuel.

[Vehicle identifier and the latest odometer reading from fuel transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObYUp.png)

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to retrieve the bottom (last) odometer reading for each vehicle registration regardless of whether that odometer reading is the highest value for that vehicle registration. Is that correct? What about zeroes?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I need to also return all of the zeroes so that I can filter them out of the current data. @Jeeped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An Array(CSE) formula solves the issue:*

[image]

- Array (CSE) formula in Cell `A92` to get unique Reg no.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$78:$A$88, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$91:A91, $A$78:$A$88), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Array(CSE) formula in Cell `C92` to get latest reading (ignores zero).

  ```
  {=MIN(IF(($A$78:$A$88=$A92)*($C$78:$C$88>0),$C$78:$C$88))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish both formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.

Comment: Hi, how would I use this formula to find the earliest date? In the same type of method that you have used there?

I tried doing it on a spreadsheet that I have but it continuously returns zero.

Comment: @DhanushManjunath,, *tell me one think first ,,, whether above shown method is working for you or not ??*,, and for earliest date ,, in place of `Column C`, use `Date Column` like `A` or `B` what so ever !!

Comment: Hey mate, yeah it works on different values but i noticed the reason why it wasn't working before was because when I downloaded the report spreadsheet it gave me values in a 'general' format, but it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help you @DhanushManjunath,, keep asing ☺