# Return earliest date from a range based on a seperate identifier?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet at my workplace where it is essentially a list of fuel transactions sorted by each vehicle. I need to be able to make a confirmation list that essentially says: 'Yes, this is the first transaction for this vehicle for this month'.

I have attached a screenshot of the type of data that I am working with, and the type of list that I am trying to make (manually entered).

NB: Yes, I could just filter by date and sort by vehicle and then look at the earliest date. But I need to make this a refreshable dump where anyone can paste in a downloaded list of transactions and be able to find the earliest date a transaction was made for each vehicle.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRVFY.png)
[image]

Let me know how you guys would go about it, cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the largest value of a cell in another column?](https://superuser.com/questions/1494312/how-do-i-find-the-largest-value-of-a-cell-in-another-column)

Comment: The formula posted in that question can indeed identify the earliest date but it requires me to make a reference to the specific ID/rego, I dont know how to make it so that i can just drag it down and it will confirm that the row that containts Y is indeed the earliest date for that vehicle.

Comment: No need to use `Y`,  simply read carefully the previous post you get the answer (*here you need to create unique Fleet ID and get earliest Date for it*),,, and if you are stick with `Y` then since `Y` itself identifies earliest date,, so better use `Vlookup` or `Index & Match`!!

Comment: Sorry Rajesh still not able to figure it out, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong